# xml same tag name on different levels

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I am trying to parse an xml document using Perl **XML::LibXML::reader** module .
The module works well and i was able to parse most of the document ,but there are sections on the xml which could have multiple elements with the same name on different levels and i didn't know how to apporach and deal with such elements ,

what I am trying to do is to convert the below strcutre to conveinent  perl data structure i tried to use **XML::Simple** and **XML::Twig** smplify subroutine (see below )in addition to XML::LibXML  but parsing this section with them is very slow(x20 slower than parsing the document without them),

```
 my @conf= eval{($copy->findnodes('criteria'))};
 my $t= XML::Twig->new();
  my $hash=$t->parse($_->toString)->simplify(forcearray =>1  ]);
  $t->purge();
```

could someone suggest how can i parse the below section to convient perl data structre with XML::LibXML::reader in faster manner.
any help with be appreciated

```
 example of such file :

 <criteria operator="OR">

    <criteria operator="AND">  -> nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:123" comment="Windows XP is installed"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:234" comment="file foo.txt exists"/>
    <criteria operator="OR"> -> nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:127" comment="file x.txt exists"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:127" comment="file y.txt exists"/>
    </criteria> 
     </criteria> 
    <criteria operator="AND" negate="true"> ->nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:345" comment="Windows 2003 is installed"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:456" comment="file fred.txt has a version less than 2"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:567" negate="true" comment=patch is installed"/>
    </criteria>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:345" comment="Windows 2003 is installed"/>
 </criteria>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convenient Perl data structure"?  That will depend on what you intend to do with the data.  Have you defined the data structure you'd like to see? What have you tried so far? Please show your code.  Without more specific information, this question is likely to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @JimGarrison i mean on convenient way is to store the high level criteria data and its sub elemetns  like on Hash and use it against data that I have on DB to check the criteria if its passed or failed.for example the for evey critrion i have a result of pass or fail on the DB and i want to check the result of the high level criteria if it failed or passed

Comment: So please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison i added my usage of XML::Twig to parse this section but its to slow,

Comment: @JimGarrison - typically people saying that want to mimique output of XML::Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to `simplify` your XML. Looking at it, the tool you're looking for is a twig handler in `XML::Twig`.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = q{ <criteria operator="OR">

    <criteria operator="AND">  -> nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:123" comment="Windows XP is installed"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:234" comment="file foo.txt exists"/>
    <criteria operator="OR"> -> nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:127" comment="file x.txt exists"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:127" comment="file y.txt exists"/>
    </criteria> 
     </criteria> 
    <criteria operator="AND" negate="true"> ->nested element
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:345" comment="Windows 2003 is installed"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:456" comment="file fred.txt has a version less than 2"/>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:567" negate="true" comment="patch is installed"/>
    </criteria>
    <criterion test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:345" comment="Windows 2003 is installed"/>
 </criteria> };

my %test_hash;

sub process_criteria {
    my ( $twig, $criteria ) = @_;
    foreach my $criterion ( $criteria->children('criterion') ) {
        my $ref     = $criterion->att('test_ref');
        my $comment = $criterion->att('comment');
        $test_hash{$ref} = $comment;
    }
}

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { criteria => \&process_criteria } )
    ->parse($xml);

print Dumper \%test_hash;
```

Now, I'm not sure this does exactly what you want, but is meant as more of an illustration of how to handle the problem.